# Kafka server running into java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument exception

Tags: apache-kafka, socketexception

I am trying to start up Kafka server locally on a macos with m1 chip. I followed the guide from the official kakfa quickstart(https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart). Zookeeper starts up fine but `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties` is giving me socket invalid argument exception below:

```
[2023-01-30 09:22:55,790] ERROR Encountered an error while configuring the connection, closing it. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Net.java:373)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.setOption(SocketChannelImpl.java:234)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setBooleanOption(SocketAdaptor.java:270)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setTcpNoDelay(SocketAdaptor.java:305)
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.configureAcceptedSocketChannel(SocketServer.scala:759)
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.accept(SocketServer.scala:737)
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.acceptNewConnections(SocketServer.scala:703)
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.run(SocketServer.scala:645)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I have tried:

1. Double checking that no other application is using the same port
2. Use a different JDK (from openjdk17 to openjdk 11 and back to 17)
3. Rebooted my machine
4. Clear up kafka related log folder under /tmp
5. Rebooted my machine
6. Used a lower version (3.2.1) of kafka tarball (since that one worked for me before but now it also runs into the same socket issue)
7. Change zookeeper port from 2181 to something else

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same exception when starting kafka server installed from brew on mac with intel chip.

In my case that might not have been antivirus issue, I solved the problem configuring listener in `server.properties` file:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Comment: Had the same issue, and this solution appears to have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be an antivirus issue. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: Same problem here on MAC. Did you solve doing anything particular?